# OpenGL 2.0 Matrices not working

Tags: java, opengl, matrix, lwjgl

I am using Java and OpenGL (LWJGL) to setup some matrices, I didn't want to use the inbuilt methods as I also want this to work on Android and so using LWJGL's Matrix classes wouldn't be appropriate. Currently    I am setting up a perspective view, using an fov of 70, znear 0.1, zfar 1000. Rotating using the current setup only results in strange results, not rotating in the correct way, and objects being scaled strangely and often disappearing.

Here is the Matrix4D class:

```
public class Matrix4D {

/* The values within this matrix */
public float[] values;

/* The default constructor */
public Matrix4D() {
    //Create the values
    this.values = new float[16];
}

/* The constructor with the values given */
public Matrix4D(float[] values) {
    //Create the values
    this.values = values;
}

/* The constructor with the values given */
public Matrix4D(float[][] values) {
    //Load the values
    load(values);
}

/* The method used to set the values given a 2 dimensional array */
public void load(float[][] values) {
    this.values = new float[] {
            values[0][0], values[0][1], values[0][2], values[0][3],
            values[1][0], values[1][1], values[1][2], values[1][3],
            values[2][0], values[2][1], values[2][2], values[2][3],
            values[3][0], values[3][1], values[3][2], values[3][3]
    };
}

/* The method used to get a value using the coordinate within this matrix */
public float get(int x, int y) {
    //Get the position
    int position = x + (y * 4);
    //Return the value
    return this.values[position];
}

/* The method used to return a string representation of this matrix */
public String toString() {
    //Return the string
    return "[ " + this.values[0] + " " + this.values[1] + " " + + this.values[2] + " " + + this.values[3] + " ]" + "\n" +
           "[ " + this.values[4] + " " + this.values[5] + " " + + this.values[6] + " " + + this.values[7] + " ]" + "\n" +
           "[ " + this.values[8] + " " + this.values[9] + " " + + this.values[10] + " " + + this.values[11] + " ]" + "\n" +
           "[ " + this.values[12] + " " + this.values[13] + " " + + this.values[14] + " " + + this.values[15] + " ]";
}

/* The method used to get the values */
public float[] getValues() { return this.values; }

/* The method used to get the values in a 2D array */
public float[][] getValues2DArray() {
    //The array
    float[][] array = new float[4][4];
    //Go through each value
    int column = 0;
    int row = 0;
    while (column * row < array.length) {
        row ++;
        if (row >= 4) {
            column++;
            row = 0;
        }
        array[column][row] = this.values[column * row];
    }
    //Return the array
    return array;
}

}
```

Here is the Matrix class (Used to setup and perform calculations on a matrix):

```
public class Matrix {

/* The different matrices */
public static Matrix4D modelMatrix = new Matrix4D();
public static Matrix4D viewMatrix = new Matrix4D();
public static Matrix4D projectionMatrix = new Matrix4D();
public static Matrix4D modelViewProjectionMatrix = new Matrix4D();

/* The static method used to load an identity matrix */
public static void loadIdentity(Matrix4D matrix) {
    //Load the identity matrix
    matrix.load(new float[][] {
            new float[] { 1, 0, 0, 0 },
            new float[] { 0, 1, 0, 0 },
            new float[] { 0, 0, 1, 0 },
            new float[] { 0, 0, 0, 1 },
    });
}

/* The static method used to add two matrices together */
public static Matrix4D add(Matrix4D matrixA, Matrix4D matrixB) {
    //Create a new matrix
    Matrix4D matrix = new Matrix4D();
    //Go through each value
    for (int a = 0; a < matrix.values.length; a++)
        //Assign the current value
        matrix.values[a] = matrixA.values[a] + matrixB.values[a];
    //Return the matrix
    return matrix;
}

/* The static method used to subtract a matrix (B) from another (A) */
public static Matrix4D subtract(Matrix4D matrixA, Matrix4D matrixB) {
    //Create a new matrix
    Matrix4D matrix = new Matrix4D();
    //Go through each value
    for (int a = 0; a < matrix.values.length; a++)
        //Assign the current value
        matrix.values[a] = matrixB.values[a] - matrixA.values[a];
    //Return the matrix
    return matrix;
}

/* The static method used to multiply two matrices together */
public static Matrix4D multiply(Matrix4D matrixA, Matrix4D matrixB) {
    //Create a new matrix
    Matrix4D matrix = new Matrix4D(new float[][] {
            new float[] {
                    (matrixA.values[0] * matrixB.values[0]) + (matrixA.values[1] * matrixB.values[4]) + (matrixA.values[2] * matrixB.values[8]) + (matrixA.values[3] * matrixB.values[12]),
                    (matrixA.values[0] * matrixB.values[1]) + (matrixA.values[1] * matrixB.values[5]) + (matrixA.values[2] * matrixB.values[9]) + (matrixA.values[3] * matrixB.values[13]),
                    (matrixA.values[0] * matrixB.values[2]) + (matrixA.values[1] * matrixB.values[6]) + (matrixA.values[2] * matrixB.values[10]) + (matrixA.values[3] * matrixB.values[14]),
                    (matrixA.values[0] * matrixB.values[3]) + (matrixA.values[1] * matrixB.values[7]) + (matrixA.values[2] * matrixB.values[11]) + (matrixA.values[3] * matrixB.values[15])
            },
            new float[] {
                    (matrixA.values[4] * matrixB.values[0]) + (matrixA.values[5] * matrixB.values[4]) + (matrixA.values[6] * matrixB.values[8]) + (matrixA.values[7] * matrixB.values[12]),
                    (matrixA.values[4] * matrixB.values[1]) + (matrixA.values[5] * matrixB.values[5]) + (matrixA.values[6] * matrixB.values[9]) + (matrixA.values[7] * matrixB.values[13]),
                    (matrixA.values[4] * matrixB.values[2]) + (matrixA.values[5] * matrixB.values[6]) + (matrixA.values[6] * matrixB.values[10]) + (matrixA.values[7] * matrixB.values[14]),
                    (matrixA.values[4] * matrixB.values[3]) + (matrixA.values[5] * matrixB.values[7]) + (matrixA.values[6] * matrixB.values[11]) + (matrixA.values[7] * matrixB.values[15])
            },
            new float[] {
                    (matrixA.values[8] * matrixB.values[0]) + (matrixA.values[9] * matrixB.values[4]) + (matrixA.values[10] * matrixB.values[8]) + (matrixA.values[11] * matrixB.values[12]),
                    (matrixA.values[8] * matrixB.values[1]) + (matrixA.values[9] * matrixB.values[5]) + (matrixA.values[10] * matrixB.values[9]) + (matrixA.values[11] * matrixB.values[13]),
                    (matrixA.values[8] * matrixB.values[2]) + (matrixA.values[9] * matrixB.values[6]) + (matrixA.values[10] * matrixB.values[10]) + (matrixA.values[11] * matrixB.values[14]),
                    (matrixA.values[8] * matrixB.values[3]) + (matrixA.values[9] * matrixB.values[7]) + (matrixA.values[10] * matrixB.values[11]) + (matrixA.values[11] * matrixB.values[15])
            },
            new float[] {
                    (matrixA.values[12] * matrixB.values[0]) + (matrixA.values[13] * matrixB.values[4]) + (matrixA.values[14] * matrixB.values[8]) + (matrixA.values[15] * matrixB.values[12]),
                    (matrixA.values[12] * matrixB.values[1]) + (matrixA.values[13] * matrixB.values[5]) + (matrixA.values[14] * matrixB.values[9]) + (matrixA.values[15] * matrixB.values[13]),
                    (matrixA.values[12] * matrixB.values[2]) + (matrixA.values[13] * matrixB.values[6]) + (matrixA.values[14] * matrixB.values[10]) + (matrixA.values[15] * matrixB.values[14]),
                    (matrixA.values[12] * matrixB.values[3]) + (matrixA.values[13] * matrixB.values[7]) + (matrixA.values[14] * matrixB.values[11]) + (matrixA.values[15] * matrixB.values[15])
            }
    });
    //Return the matrix
    return matrix;
}

/* The static method used to transpose a matrix */
public static Matrix4D transpose(Matrix4D matrix) {
    //Get the values from the matrix
    float[][] values = matrix.getValues2DArray();
    //The new values
    float[][] newValues = new float[4][4];
    //Go through the array
    for (int y = 0; y < values.length; y++) {
        for (int x = 0; x < values[y].length; x++) {
            //Assign the new value
            newValues[x][y] = values[y][x];
        }
    }
    //Return the matrix
    return new Matrix4D(newValues);
}

/* The static method used to translate a matrix */
public static Matrix4D translate(Matrix4D matrix, Vector3D vector) {
    //The transform matrix
    Matrix4D transform = new Matrix4D(new float[][] {
            new float[] { 0, 0, 0, vector.x },
            new float[] { 0, 0, 0, vector.y },
            new float[] { 0, 0, 0, vector.z },
            new float[] { 0, 0, 0, 0 },
    });
    //Add onto the matrix and return the result
    return add(matrix, transform);
}

/* The static method used to rotate a matrix */
public static Matrix4D rotate(Matrix4D matrix, float angle, int x, int y, int z) {
    //The transform matrix
    Matrix4D transform = new Matrix4D();
    //Calculate the values needed
    float cos = (float) Math.cos(angle);
    float sin = (float) Math.sin(angle);
    //Check the x y and z values
    if (x == 1) {
        transform.load(new float[][] {
                new float[] { 0, 0, 0, 0 },
                new float[] { 0, cos, -sin, 0 },
                new float[] { 0, sin, cos, 0 },
                new float[] { 0, 0, 0, 0 },
        });
    } else if (y == 1) {
        transform.load(new float[][] {
                new float[] { cos, 0, sin, 0 },
                new float[] { 0, 0, 0, 0 },
                new float[] { -sin, 0, cos, 0 },
                new float[] { 0, 0, 0, 0 },
        });
    } else if (z == 1) {
        transform.load(new float[][] {
                new float[] { cos, -sin, 0, 0 },
                new float[] { sin, cos, 0, 0 },
                new float[] { 0, 0, 0, 0 },
                new float[] { 0, 0, 0, 0 },
        });
    }
    //Add onto the matrix and return the result
    return add(matrix, transform);
}

/* The static method used to scale a matrix */
public static Matrix4D scale(Matrix4D matrix, Vector3D vector) {
    //The transform matrix
    Matrix4D transform = new Matrix4D(new float[][] {
            new float[] { vector.x, 0, 0, 0 },
            new float[] { 0, vector.y, 0, 0 },
            new float[] { 0, 0, vector.z, 0 },
            new float[] { 0, 0, 0, 0 },
    });
    //Add onto the matrix and return the result
    return add(matrix, transform);
}

/* The static method used to return an orthographic projection matrix */
public static Matrix4D ortho(float left, float right, float top, float bottom, float zfar, float znear) {
    return new Matrix4D(new float[][] {
            new float[] { 2 / (right - left), 0, 0, -((right + left) / (right - left)) },
            new float[] { 0, 2 / (top - bottom), 0, -((top + bottom) / (top - bottom)) },
            new float[] { 0, 0, -2 / (zfar - znear), -((zfar + znear) / (zfar - znear)) },
            new float[] { 0, 0, 0, 1 },
    });
}

/* The static method used to return a perspective projection matrix */
public static Matrix4D perspective(float fov, float aspect, float zNear, float zFar) {
    float f = (float) (1f / Math.tan(fov / 2f));
    return new Matrix4D(new float[][] {
            new float[] { f / aspect, 0, 0, 0 },
            new float[] { 0, f, 0, 0 },
            new float[] { 0, 0, (zFar + zNear) / (zFar - zNear), (2 * zFar * zNear) / (zNear - zFar) },
            new float[] { 0, 0, -1, 0 },
    });
}

}
```

Finally the method used to setup the perspective/orthographic projection is:

```
/* The static method to setup an orthographic view given the width, height
 * znear and zfar values */
public static void setupOrtho(float width, float height, float znear , float zfar) {
    Matrix.loadIdentity(Matrix.modelMatrix);
    Matrix.loadIdentity(Matrix.viewMatrix);
    Matrix.projectionMatrix = Matrix.ortho(0, width, 0, height, znear, zfar);
}

/* The static method used to setup a perspective view given the
 * fov, z near and z far value */
public static void setupPerspective(float fov, float zNear, float zFar) {
    setupPerspective(fov, (float) (Settings.Window.Width / Settings.Window.Height), zNear, zFar);
}

/* The static method used to setup a perspective view given the
 * fov, aspect ratio, z near and z far values */
public static void setupPerspective(float fov, float aspect, float zNear, float zFar) {
    Matrix.loadIdentity(Matrix.modelMatrix);
    Matrix.loadIdentity(Matrix.viewMatrix);
    Matrix.projectionMatrix = Matrix.perspective(fov, aspect, zNear, zFar);
}
```

To render all of this and pass the matrices to the shader I am using

```
    //Multiply the matrices together
    Matrix4D modelViewMatrix = Matrix.multiply(Matrix.modelMatrix, Matrix.viewMatrix);
    Matrix.modelViewProjectionMatrix = (Matrix.multiply(modelViewMatrix, Matrix.projectionMatrix));
    System.out.println(Matrix.modelViewProjectionMatrix.toString() + "\n");
```

And in the shader I multiply the current vertices position by the model view projection marix.

Here is a picture of what it currently looks like.

[image: What the output currently looks like]

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be multiplying your matrices in the wrong order. When combining matrix transformations, the one on the right of the equation will be the first transformation performed.

You calculate your matrix as Model × View × Projection. When multiplying this by a vector, the projection would be performed first, followed by the view transformation, and lastly the model transformation. Obviously this is not what you want.

Your final matrix should be calculated like Projection × View × Model to do the transformations in the right order.

Comment: I just tried that, still not quite right though. I added some pictures of what happens. Would it have something to do with the order of transformations, I think I am currently scaling, rotating then translating.

Comment: You actually aren't calculating your translation, rotation and scale matrices properly. To properly apply the transformation to the matrix that you're passing to the function, you should multiply the new one rather than add. You also need to have 1s in the main diagonal for this to work.